# Pythonic way to map optional parameters to a compulsory one if None

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have a function like this:

```
def func(foo, bar, nin=None, nout=None):
    if not nin:
        nin = bar
    if not nout:
        nout = bar
    return foo * nin / nout
```

It takes in two optional parameters and I need to map them into another compulsory parameter if they are not passed in. But is this the pythonic way to do it? Are there other ways to get the check and set the `nin` and `nout`?

Comment: Yes, that's the Pythonic way to do it, except that you should check `if nin is not None:` instead of `if not nin:` to avoid issues with false-y objects *other than `None`*.

Comment: Looks good, though I would use `if nin is None: ...` etc.

Comment: You could also  use **kwargs and use .get,  `nin, nout = kwargs.get("nin", bar),kwargs.get("nout", foo)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to shorten it, you could do e.g.:

```
nin = bar if nin is None else nin
```

Note that here I'm testing for `None` by *identity*, using `is`, not *truthiness*; otherwise, what happens if e.g. `nin = 0`? This isn't `None`, but still evaluates false-y (see [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)), hence the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)'s suggestion:

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is`
>   or `is not` ... beware of writing `if x` when you really mean 
>   `if x is not None` -- e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that
>   defaults to `None` was set to some other value. The other value might
>   have a type (such as a container) that could be false in a boolean
>   context!

Comment: Different case, you could test with `==` here as well.. `is` just feels like the way here (and is probably slightly faster)

Comment: @lolopop you could, but, again, the style guide is clear on this!

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

```
def func(foo, bar, nin=None, nout=None):
    nin = bar if nin is None else nin
    nout = bar if nout is None else nout
    return foo * nin / nout
```

Answer (score 1):

`None` is the way for inputs where you also accept zero and the like.

I think that you should use `nin is None` rather the `nin == None`, and many would argue that `nin = bar if nin is None else nin` is more pythonic, but personally I think both are ok.